# How to parse this timestamp (42583.906678) format?

Tags: python, datetime, gis

I have this timestamp (42583.906678) from the combine harvester for the yield map.
Timestamp: 42583.906678
I need to convert this in DateTime format in python.

More examples for timestamps:

```
42583.913414
42583.913426
42583.913437
42583.913449
42583.913461
42583.913472
42583.913484
```

All these timestamps represent the same date, i.e. 04.09.2015

Comment: Those are not valid timestamps, at least not in the common sense of timestamps. What date are they supposed to represent and according to what logic? The current timestamp is 1641297122 (seconds since 1.1.1970).

Comment: This looks like the number of days since January, 1st 1900. Meaning these all fall on August 2nd, 2016. Is that correct?

Comment: So all these timestamps are for the same date, i.e. 04.09.2015. Yes, I checked this too, it is not unix epoch format.

Comment: @luk2302 those are Excel serial dates - pretty valid if you ask me (you don't have to like Excel for that ;-)).